# Where is the 2014/15 College Scorecard Data (US Dept. of Education)?

Tags: collegescorecard

The U.S. Department of Education's [College Scorecard Data](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/) download is only giving me 1996 through 2013, yet the description under "Download the Data" implies that there should be 2014 and 2015 data in the download. The option to download the most recent data under "Featured Downloads" downloads data for 2013. **Is the 2014/2015 data available? If so, where is it?**

Comment: Can you help us with the website you are trying to download from?

Comment: https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/

Answer (score 1):

Most of the data on student outcomes (e.g., completion rates, repayment rates, and debt measures) are not available past the 2013-14 year at this time.  For some elements, like the earnings data, the most recent data available describe cohorts measured in the 2011 and 2012 tax years. However, a few elements—including header data like institutional name and address, Minority Serving Institution status, currently operating status, and HCM2 status—are more recent. These data are, for the purposes of convenience, also included in the 2013 file (which comprises both 2013 and other more recent data). In our next annual update, we will add another file, which will include 2014-15 data for may outcomes, as well as more recent data related to the institution. We recognize this can be an unwieldy way to work with the data, so we will continue to explore ways to make this information clearer and easier to access.